# Day of the Week to Return 'weekend' or 'weekday'

Tags: r, dayofweek, weekend

I'm brand new to R... I have a column in a data frame where I extracted the days of the week from a date-time column.  I would like to add another column to show either "weekend" or "weekday".
Where "Sat" and "Sun" return "weekend" and
"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri" return "weekday"

| day_of_week | wkend_wkday |
| --- | --- |
| Sat |  |
| Mon |  |
| Wed |  |
| Sun |  |
| Fri |  |
| Tue |  |
| Sat |  |
| Wed |  |
| Mon |  |

I have tried some `ifelse()` statements, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` with `ifelse` to check whether the day in `day_of_week` column matches `c("Sat", "Sun")` vector. If it does,the `ifelse` function returns `weekend`. Otherwise, it returns `weekday`. :

```
dat

#  day_of_week
#1         Sat
#2         Mon
#3         Wed
#4         Sun
#5         Fri
#6         Tue
#7         Sat
#8         Wed
#9         Mon

dat$wkend_wkday <- ifelse(dat$day_of_week %in% c("Sat", "Sun"), "weekend", "weekday") 

dat
#  day_of_week wkend_wkday
#1         Sat     weekend
#2         Mon     weekday
#3         Wed     weekday
#4         Sun     weekend
#5         Fri     weekday
#6         Tue     weekday
#7         Sat     weekend
#8         Wed     weekday
#9         Mon     weekday
```

Comment: Nice. Please kindly accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I did. Thanks again!